# Test plan configuration in VSTS Visual Studio Test task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Is it possible to get a Test Plan's test configuration in the VSTS Visual Studio Test task?

I've looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/variables?tabs=batch#default-variables but can't find it listed.

Answer (score 0):

No, we cannot get the test configuration in Visual Studio Test task, no such a predefined variable.

However we can get the test configuration via the REST API:

E.g:

Get a list of test configurations:

```
GET https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/fabrikam-fiber-tfvc/_apis/test/configurations?api-version=3.0-preview.2
```

Get a specific test configuration:

```
GET https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/test/configurations/{configurationId}?api-version={version}
```

Refer to [Test configurations](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/configurations) for details.

Comment: @Matt Horrocks Is the REST API works for you? any update?